# Alert Message Does not Show in screen while a record delete from Database

Tags: java, javafx

Hello I have a problem   when I am trying to validate if the record exist in this method, the alert dialog its ok, in the screen appears  "registro no encontrado", but when i write the correct record to delete does not appear alert dialog "registro borrado correctamente" but it does delete the record, any idea what could possible i am doing wrong?, regards.

this is my Code.

```
public void borraregistro() {

             Integer numfac=null;
             String consulta=" delete  from auditoriac where numero_factura=? ";

             Connection conn=null;{

                  try {
                      try {
                             numfac = Integer.parseInt(borrar.getText());
                         }catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                             Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
                              alert.setTitle("Informacion");
                              alert.setHeaderText(null);
                              alert.setContentText("Campo Vacio, Por favor Digite el numero de Factura:" +ex);
                              alert.getDialogPane().setStyle("-fx-text-fill: white;\r\n" + 
                                        "    -fx-border-color:  rgb(238, 201, 91);\r\n" + 
                                        "    -fx-border-radius: 5;\r\n" + 
                                        "    -fx-padding: 10 2 10 -2;\r\n" + 
                                        "    -fx-background-color:linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffcc 15%, #ffcc99 91%);\r\n" + 
                                        "    -fx-text-fill:black;\r\n" + 
                                        "    -fx-font-family: Oswald;\r\n" + 
                                        "    -fx-font-size:15px;    ");
                              alert.showAndWait();      



                         }
                      conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-4JA6SFR:1433;databaseName=GLOSASNINO", "sa", "123");
                      PreparedStatement ps =conn.prepareStatement(consulta);
                      ps.setInt(1, numfac);
                      ps.executeUpdate(); 
                      int comparar =ps.executeUpdate(); 
                     if (comparar==0){
                            Alert alerta = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
                              alerta.setTitle("Informacion");
                              alerta.setHeaderText(null);
                              alerta.setContentText("Registro no encontrado");
                              alerta.getDialogPane().setStyle("-fx-text-fill: white;\r\n" + 
                                        "    -fx-border-color:  rgb(238, 201, 91);\r\n" + 
                                        "    -fx-border-radius: 5;\r\n" + 
                                        "    -fx-padding: 10 2 10 -2;\r\n" + 
                                        "    -fx-background-color:linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffcc 15%, #ffcc99 91%);\r\n" + 
                                        "    -fx-text-fill:black;\r\n" + 
                                        "    -fx-font-family: Oswald;\r\n" + 
                                        "    -fx-font-size:15px;    ");
                              alerta.showAndWait();  

                         }


                     else {  
                              Alert alerta = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
                              alerta.setTitle("Informacion");
                              alerta.setHeaderText(null);
                              alerta.setContentText("Registro borrado correctamente");
                              alerta.getDialogPane().setStyle("-fx-text-fill: white;\r\n" + 
                                        "    -fx-border-color:  rgb(238, 201, 91);\r\n" + 
                                        "    -fx-border-radius: 5;\r\n" + 
                                        "    -fx-padding: 10 2 10 -2;\r\n" + 
                                        "    -fx-background-color:linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffcc 15%, #ffcc99 91%);\r\n" + 
                                        "    -fx-text-fill:black;\r\n" + 
                                        "    -fx-font-family: Oswald;\r\n" + 
                                        "    -fx-font-size:15px;    ");
                              alerta.showAndWait();  

                             }



                  }catch (SQLException e) {

                  }

             }

             seleccionaregistros();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are executing your update twice:

```
ps.executeUpdate(); 
int comparar = ps.executeUpdate();
```

The record is deleted on your first call to the `executeUpdate()` method. On the next line when you call the method again and set the `comparar` variable, there is nothing left to delete so 0 rows are affected.

Remove the first `ps.executeUpdate()` and you should see a different result.